# How to solve $\tan(x+100)=\tan(x+50)\tan(x)\tan(x-50)?$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

The question is The minimum value of x for which $\tan(x+100)=\tan(x+50)\tan(x)\tan(x-50)$

Here is what I've tried so far:

In the R.H.S-  $$\frac {\sin(x+50)\sin(x-50)\sin(x)}{\cos(x+50)\cos(x-50)\cos(x)}\implies \frac {(\sin^2x-\sin^250)\sin x}{(\cos^2x-\sin^250)\cos x}$$

But, I think I am proceeding wrong because my process is not yielding any result.
Kindly help me out.

Comment: are the given angles in degrees?

Comment: They are in degrees, sir!

Comment: Where is that question coming from?

Comment: Do you mean which book? @Arnaldo

Comment: Is it from a book?

Comment: Yes! I was trying to solve a book on trigo.

Comment: $$
\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B
$$